# Running my Oracle DB query through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, oracle-11g

I'm automating my deployment process with the help of Jenkins.

Running my bat file and I've done all the code deployment process.

Now I want to deploy my DB scripts to the corresponding DB servers.

Is there any Plugin or can I do it through my bat file itself which one is easier and best.

Can someone give me an idea.

I searched the solution on online all referring to SQLPlus Script Runner Plugin

I'm not aware of that plugin is that good. Can I use the same for my deployment.

For deploying the DB scripts through SQLPlus Script Runner plugin is that alone or I've to install oracle client on my build server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to install the Oracle Instantclient with Sqlplus.